# How to set cell value dependent on another celll

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I ask a question a few days ago hoping to get a response, the problem was that i wasnt specific enough for people to understand what i really wanted so im going to try to be super specific this time, here we go....

I got a strange task to perform and I can't imagine how to do it or even come up with a term to google, since I'm not that good with excel formulas.

1. In cell "B3" there is the number 19.90. That cell controls the cell "C13" so when cell "B3" equals 19.90 the cell in "C13" will also be 19.90 (C13=B3 is the formula). the other cells in column "C" (C12 and C14) will also change if "B3" changes because they have this formula (C13-0.01) and (C13+0.01)So as you can see if "B3" changes everything changes

Now here goes the difficult part

2. The number that is in the cell "B6" will always appear on column C ALWAYS. So if you change the cell "B3" (that controls everything) the number that is in cell "B6" will always have to be in column C. In this example its on cell "C14".
3. I want to multiply the cell "B2" X 0.01 that equals = 10,0000. And i want that number to appear next to the cell that contains 19.91 (that is dependent on cell "B6" like i mentioned before) in this case "D14".

i hope you can see the problem here...

The problem is that i want the number 10,000 to be next to the cell that contains 19.91 in column C but if you change the number in cell "B3" everything changes and the number 10,000 will no longer be next to 19.91

[image]

here is a picture for to see what im talking about

what i tried did not work

Comment: Please tell us what you tried. A screen cap of the end result would also be useful (I, at least, am not 100% sure what you mean

Comment: Put `=IF(B$6=C12,B$1*0.01,"")` in `C12`and populate down to `C14` maybe?

Comment: thank you for trying, it sort of worked. Would you be intersted in trying to explain 1 on 1. Of course ill pay you for your time thank you (:

Comment: I believe this would defeat the purpose of S.O., you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77189707/edit) to show us what you tried (this could include my suggestions) and explain how it fails to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Apply formula `=IF(D12=$B$6,$B$2*0.01,"")` on cell E12, fill through E14. It will update the cells with the value from cell B2 multiplied by 0.01 if the cell in column D equals the value in cell B6. Otherwise, it will leave the cell blank.

[image]

---

**Update**

> Question: what i meant was for the cell to the right of 19.90 to be 0. So for example 19.91=10,000 i wanted for 19.90=0 and 19.89=-10,000

Formula: `=IF(D12=$B$6,$B$2*0.01,IF(ABS(D12)=0.01,$B$2*D12,0))`

[image]

Comment: Holy guacamole it worked! Now the only thing that i would like to do is for the 19.90 to be 0 and then 19.89 to be -10,000 (im talking about your right example) thank you

Comment: I have updated the formula.

Comment: oh sorry i messed up what i meant was for the cell to the right of 19.90 to be 0. So for example 19.91=10,000 i wanted for 19.90=0 and 19.89=-10,000 sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Is it the final expected result?

Comment: yes so it would be like "D14"=19.91 and "E14"=10,000 then "D13"=19.90 and "E13"=0 then "D12"=19.89 and "E12"=-10,000

Comment: and that would be the final result

Comment: Pls check the updated formula.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! you got next level knowledge dude thanks again